# Spring Boot and @KafkaListener

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using Spring Boot 2.7 with Kafka integration for consuming records.

Here's my listener, very simple :

```
@KafkaListener(topics = {"journal-topic1"})
public void onMessage(List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> records) {
    //processing
}
```

My problem is : I don't get `List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>>` but a list of my values : `List<String>`

Here is my config :

```
spring:
  kafka:
    topic: "journal-topic1"
    properties:
      auto-create-topics-enable: true
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      group-id: "journal-group1"
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      auto-offset-reset: latest
    admin:
      properties:
        bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
```

Comment: Please provide 1) your library file (pom.xml, gradle…) 2) Please edit your code area by adding the java import.

Comment: You need to explicitly enable batch consumer factory.

Answer (score 1):

Please give more details, but for now try to change your code to consume `ConsumerRecord` and not List.

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = {"journal-topic1"})
public void message(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
    //Process
}
```

or else if you want to consumer entire batch of consumer records view there :

[*Kafka listener receiving List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>>, is it possible to consume?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54361329/kafka-listener-receiving-listconsumerrecordstring-string-is-it-possible-to)

Comment: It works fine with a single record... but not a List :(

Comment: Have you seen the link in answer ? What problem do you have with a List?

Comment: You can now add `batch = true` to the `@KafkaListener`, to override the factory setting.